# Are appengine backend shutdown hooks random?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am having problem with shutdown code. So I made a minimal backend servlet to test this.

Anyone out there that knows if shutdown hooks are reliable or not!?

My logs do not show any **_ah/stop** line at all ... at the moment.

I suspect that it could be related to that the logs disappears but would like to get that confirmed. I.e. that **ApiProxi.flushLogs()** does not work in shutdown mode.

One funny note is that when I got mad and duplicated the line (15 times) ...

```
            log.info("LIFECYCLE - Shutdown hook invoked");
```

... I saw **_ah/stop** lines.

```
@Override
public void destroy() {
    super.destroy();
    log.info("LIFECYCLE - Shutting down");
    ApiProxy.flushLogs();
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    log.info("doGet()");
    ApiProxy.flushLogs();
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    log.info("doPost()");
    ApiProxy.flushLogs();
}




@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    log.info("LIFECYCLE - Starting up");
    ApiProxy.flushLogs();
    LifecycleManager.getInstance().setShutdownHook(new ShutdownHook() {
        public void shutdown() {
            log.info("LIFECYCLE - Shutdown hook invoked");
            ApiProxy.flushLogs();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void destroy() {
    super.destroy();
    log.info("LIFECYCLE - Shutting down");
    ApiProxy.flushLogs();
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    log.info("doGet()");
    ApiProxy.flushLogs();
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    log.info("doPost()");
    ApiProxy.flushLogs();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the manual?

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/?hl=en#Shutdown

You can manually shutdown your backend to trigger the shutdown handler.  But yes, they can happen randomly.

Comment: Of course they can! The problem is that my shutdown code does not get called!

Answer (score 0):

It does seem that the shutdown handler is not guaranteed to be called. This happens to my app almost all the time. I am using python2.7 and register a shutdown handler to log some information. Does not get called 95% of the time. Backend log says proces terminated as backend took too long to shut down.